# matlab double to symbolic conversion

Tags: matlab, double, symbolic-math

Is it possible to relax the tolerance on using sym (or any other method) to convert a double precision number to a symbolic expression in matlab? For example:

```
sym(1.732050807568899) = 3900231685777031/2251799813685248
```

rather than sqrt(3).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to output of `sym` to be `sqrt(3)`?

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

I recommend applying the `sqrt` function after defining a symbolic `3`:

```matlab
rt3 = sqrt(sym(3));
```

While `sym(sqrt(3))` may work just as well, I like defining simple numbers as symbolic prior to applying functions on them.  More below

### Long Answer

By default, `sym` attempts to find a rational equivalent to a numeric literal passed to them.  However, due to a number of factors (e.g., floating-point precision limits, algorithmic limits placed on the conversion, the fact that the Rationals are a smaller set than the Reals), the conversion will not be exact in general.  However, `sym` continues to get better with every iteration and can make good conversions given `double` data:

```matlab
>> sym(1./[1:2:11])
ans =
[ 1, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, 1/11]

>> sym(sqrt(2:2:12))
ans =
[ 2^(1/2), 2, 6^(1/2), 2*2^(1/2), 10^(1/2), 2*3^(1/2)]
```

But there are still limitations when it comes to general doubles and values with small decimal components:

```matlab
>> sym(rand())
ans =
1143795557080799/9007199254740992

>> sym(1./[ 1E4+1 , 1E5+1 ])
ans =
[ 1/10001, 5902899074596311/590295810358705651712]
```

And I therefore recommend to apply symbolic conversion to variables or values that are either whole numbers or have a small decimal components (simple/obvious rational) before performing any operation on them:

```matlab
>> 1./sym([ 1E4+1 , 1E5+1 ])
ans =
[ 1/10001, 1/100001]

>> sqrt(sym(1:2:9))
ans =
[ 1, 3^(1/2), 5^(1/2), 7^(1/2), 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, Troy. The problem is that I'm obtaining 1.732050807568899 from a black-box numerical routine. It also outputs multiples of sqrts and fractions.

Comment: @lenzinho Unless the black-box can take symbolic variables or has some other way to increase the numerical precision of the result, I think you'll need to eat the `1E-14` error in the rational approximation.