# how drop near zero terms Matlab symbolic

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm doing some symbolic matrix manipulations with complex value matrices.  Some of my results are as below.

```
Zaa*(1 + 3i/36028797018963968) + Zab*(1 + 3i/36028797018963968)
```

Is there a way to tell Matlab to ignore those near zero imaginary results so the answer is reported simply as,

```
Zaa + Zab
```

**UPDATE 1**:  To provide the full background on how I am getting these results.  I am doing a calculation power electrical engineers call the similarity transformation.  It is used in symmetrical component analysis of power system faults and involves a complex transformation matrix and complex impedance values (the later are my symbolic variables Zaa, Zab etc.).

Similarity transformation:
[image]

Where A is the 3x3 shown below and  [image]

[image]

So, the full transformation calculation looks like this (the 1/3 scale factor comes from inverting A),

[image]

Here is my Matlab code (requires Symbolic Toolbox)

```
syms Zaa Zab Zac Zba Zbb Zbc Zca Zcb Zcc
Z = [Zaa Zab Zac; Zba Zbb Zbc; Zca Zcb Zcc]
a = -1/2+sqrt(3)/2*1i
A = [1 1 1; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2]
Z012 = inv(A)*Z*A
```

**Final Update**: After @holcher solved my problem I thought I'd post the finished code.

```
syms Zaa Zab Zac Zba Zbb Zbc Zca Zcb Zcc
Z = [Zaa Zab Zac; Zba Zbb Zbc; Zca Zcb Zcc]
a = -1/2+sqrt(sym(3))/2*1i
A = [1 1 1; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2]
Z012 = inv(A)*Z*A
vpa(Z012,2)
```

p.s. The [parallel question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558529/how-drop-near-zero-terms-in-octave-symbolic) I had regarding solving this in Octave was also answered but required slightly different code. This final code runs in both Matlab & Octave.

Comment: I would suggest just calling a custom function on your complex entries before multiplying with your symbols, that checks whether or not the imaginary part is small compared to the real part, and outputs the real part if it is. Then in your code it's just `Zaa*myfun(1 + 3i/36028797018963968) + Zab*myfun(1 + 3i/36028797018963968)`

Comment: Hi @billbokeey, I don't think this applies in my case.  I updated my answer so you can see where my problem originates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why is this happening? It appears that you are mixing floating point values in with your symbolic math. Most numerical values do not have exact representations in floating point, resulting in small remainder values showing as in this case. The value `3/36028797018963968` is equal to `(3/8)*eps`. There are a few workarounds that may help you:

1. You can try representing parameters as symbolic variables and substituting in the floating point values later in your code via [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).
2. You can take care in how you convert floating point values to symbolic values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648641/matlab-double-to-symbolic-conversion) for more including a simple example of when this can occur. You might also take a look at the numeric conversion flag options for the [`sym`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#bun735q-flag) function.
3. Consider using [assumptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-for-symbolic-objects.html) to restrict the domain of applicable symbolic variables to be real-valued if that is the case (Matlab symbolic variables are complex by default – this is why you will likely get a more complicated result if you call `real` or `imag` on your expression than you may expect). See [`assumptions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions.html), [`assume`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.assume.html), and the options for [`syms`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html#buod73_-set).
4. Try calling [`simplify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) on a symbolic result prior to converting it to variable precision or floating point. The idea here is to possibly minimize mathematical operations that could contribute to numerical issues.

If none of those refactoring approaches work, you will need to write a function that evaluates your symbolic expression with a tolerance you specify for what you consider to be zero. This is non-trivial to implement in a general sense and is further complicated when working in the complex-valued domain.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and informative answer.  I updated my answer to show what computation I'm doing to get here.  Right now the best I can do is vpa(ans, 2) on the result and then manually go in and delete the near-zero results.  It seems odd that a numerical result is offered with no ability to filter these remarkably small values.  p.s. I multiply the answer by 3 before I do the vpa to get coefficient 1 in most places.

Comment: @relayman357 Have you tried replacing `sqrt(3)` in your example with `sqrt(sym(3))` like my second suggestion points to? When I do this and apply `simplify` on the `Z012` I no longer see any near-zero terms when I convert using `vpa`. I'll add the use of `simplify` in my answer.

Comment: Another thing that may be occurring in your example is that use of `inv` could result in less stable results when converting from symbolic to variable precision or floating point. For purely symbolic cases `inv` is fine, but for floating point it's generally not numerically wise to use. Instead, you should use [`mldivide`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mldivide.html), e.g., `Z012 = (A\Z)*A`. So, in other words, it's possible the structure of the symbolic expressions returned by `inv` may not be as amenable to numerical conversion and result in larger errors. (Don't quote me on this.)

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic.  Thank you @horchler!  Exactly what it needed!  The sym(3) did the trick.  Just to document, I had a [parallel question using Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558529/how-drop-near-zero-terms-in-octave-symbolic).  But, Octave won't accept the sym(3).