# how drop near zero terms in Octave symbolic

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534142/how-drop-near-zero-terms-matlab-symbolic) I describe a symbolic computation I'm doing in Matlab that results in some terms remarkably small, near zero.  I can run the same code in Octave (after loading the symbolic engine with `pkg load symbolic` in command window) and get the same results.

```
syms Zaa Zab Zac Zba Zbb Zbc Zca Zcb Zcc;
Z = [Zaa Zab Zac; Zba Zbb Zbc; Zca Zcb Zcc]
a = -1/2+sqrt(3)/2*1i;
A = [1 1 1; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2];
Z012 = inv(A)*Z*A
```

Is there a way to tell Octave to make those near-zero values actually zero?

Sample result: `Zaa*(1/3 + i/36028797018963968)`

Would like rounded to: `Zaa*(1/3)`

**Update 1**: My [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534142/how-drop-near-zero-terms-matlab-symbolic) on this issue in Matlab has been answered - the solution being to use **sqrt(sym(3))** in the a equation instead of just **sqrt(3)**. That solution doesn't work in Octave however.  If I run the code below in Octave I get the error blurb shown at bottom.

Code:

```
syms Zaa Zab Zac Zba Zbb Zbc Zca Zcb Zcc;
Z = [Zaa Zab Zac; Zba Zbb Zbc; Zca Zcb Zcc]
a = -1/2+sqrt(sym(3))/2*1i;  % the sym(3) helps as
A = [1 1 1; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2];
Z012 = inv(A)*Z*A
vpa(3*Z012,2)  % to clean up the display (remember to put a 1/3 factor in front of result)
```

Here is the resulting error blurb:

```
Symbolic pkg v3.0.0: Python communication link active, SymPy v1.10.1.
Z = (sym 3x3 matrix)

  [Zaa  Zab  Zac]
  [             ]
  [Zba  Zbb  Zbc]
  [             ]
  [Zca  Zcb  Zcc]

warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym"
warning: called from
    double_to_sym_heuristic at line 50 column 7
    sym at line 379 column 13
    plus at line 53 column 5
    symbolic_similarity_transformation at line 11 column 3

error: octave_base_value::map_value(): wrong type argument 'scalar'
```

**Final update:** This code runs in both Octave and Matlab and gives identical results.

```
syms Zaa Zab Zac Zba Zbb Zbc Zca Zcb Zcc;
Z = [Zaa Zab Zac; Zba Zbb Zbc; Zca Zcb Zcc]
a = -1/2+sqrt(sym(3))/2*1i;  
A = [[1 1 1]; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2];
Z012 = inv(A)*Z*A
vpa(3*Z012,2)  % to clean up the display (remember to put a 1/3 factor in front of result)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you update the question to clarify?

Comment: Added Update 1 to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a row contains all non-sym entries then you need to define such a row as a row vector to concatenate it with sym rows. i.e. `A` should be this:

```
A = [[1 1 1]; 1 a^2 a; 1 a a^2];   %works in both Octave and MATLAB
%    ↑     ↑
```